# How to take a screenshot of current Activity and then share it for all social Media code apply sdk<24

Tags: android, screenshot

I am making an application in Android in which I have to take a screenshot of one of my activities and mail it as an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class name **TakeScreenShot**

```
//method to create a bitmap

 

       public static Bitmap getScreenShot(View view) {
                View screenView = view.getRootView();
                screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
                screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                return bitmap;
                }
    
    //method to share an image 
    
    public static void shareScreen(Bitmap bitmap, Activity activity, String nameChannel) {
            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(activity.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title", null);
                Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);
    
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.setType("image/*");
    
    
                intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, activity.getString(R.string.app_name));
                intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Watch " + nameChannel + " Channel From " + activity.getString(R.string.app_name)
                        + " Download now from google play" + " http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + activity.getPackageName());
                intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    
    
                try {
                    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Screenshot"));
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "No App Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error on sharing", e + " ");
                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "App not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

// Check permissions

public static boolean checkPermission(String permission, Activity activity) {
        int check = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission);
        return (check == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        }

// Take permissions


public static void takePermission(Activity activity) {
        String[] arrayPermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET
        , Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        , Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayPermission, Constants.PERMISSION_CODE);
        }
```

on your class create button:

```
imgBtnShare.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (TakeScreenShot.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET,this)
        || TakeScreenShot.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,this)
        || TakeScreenShot.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,this)) {
        TakeScreenShot.shareScreen(TakeScreenShot.getScreenShot(lyBackground),this,channelModel.getChannelName());
        }else {
        TakeScreenShot.takePermission(this);
        }
        });
```